What are the implications of a test procedure that only controls for FWER in the weak sense?
I'm fairly new to multiple testing. My question is mainly conceptual (and not a rigorous one).
Let's say we have a testing procedure $(T)$ that controls for the familywise error rate (FWER) in the weak sense, but not in the strong sense -- and this is shown using large simulations. I'm using weak and strong definitions from here.
Let's set the significance level to $\alpha$ and have a total of $N$ tests done using this procedure.
Assume the cases where the null model holds in all tests, that is, $H_0^i$ holds $\forall i = 1, 2\ldots N$. Weak control implies that $T$ will yield significance for alteast one test in atmost $(100\times\alpha)\%$ cases.
Now, if we apply this test procedure to actual data that was collected, and if this test yields significance in some of the tests, what are the conclusions that can be drawn from this? Can we conclude that all null models are not true, and atleast one test is significant, but among the tests that were significant, some of those are false positives?
